# Matrix null space matrix and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the linear transformation $T ∶ M_2(R) → M_2(R)$ given by

$T(A) = tr(B^T*A)*B$

, where B= $\left[\begin{array}{l}1&0\\2&-1\end{array}\right]$ and $B^T$ is the transpose of B, I need to find the null space N(T) and a basis for N(T).

Supposedly, for the expression as a whole to represent the zero matrix, the trace $tr(B^T*A)$ needs to be zero.
Since the trace of $B^T$ already is zero, is seems obvious that A must be the identity matrix or any multiple of the identity matrix.

So, surely $N(T)=span(A)$, where A is the identity matrix, with $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ forming the basis.

But as far as I can understand $N(T)=span(A)$ means any possible combination of the vectors of the basis, whereas in this case case the coefficient of the vectors forming the basis must be equal?

Also, is there a method to show that $A$ indeed needs to be a multiple of the identity matrix?

Comment: Note: $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are not basis vectors of any space of $2\times 2$ matrices since they are vectors. Also, while the identity matrix lies in $N(T)$, it is not obvious that $N(T)$ should only include multiples of the identity matrix. Your reasoning in the last four paragraphs is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

$T(A) = 0$ is equivalent to $tr(B^T A) = 0$, as you correctly noted.

Let us write $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$. Then $B^T A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} + 2a_{21} & a_{12} + 2a_{22} \\ -a_{21} & -a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$.

Thus, any matrix $A$ that satisfies $$tr(B^T A) = a_{11}+2a_{21}-a_{22} = 0$$ is an element of the nullspace $N(T)$. This includes the identity matrix, as you noticed, but also any other matrices that satisfy the equation above, i.e.

$$N(T) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{11} +2a_{21}\end{pmatrix} : a_{11},a_{12},a_{21} \in\mathbb R\right\}$$

An example for a basis of $N(T)$ would be

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. A question: How do you determine a possible basis? Why does it need three elements?

Comment: @Orm The space of $2\times 2$ matrices is $4$-dimensional. $N(T)$ is given by a restriction that eliminates one parameter / dimension out of these, so it has $3$ dimensions. You find a basis of $N(T)$ by just selecting three elements that are linearly independent.